# Azure HTTP Trigger C# Not Returning Response to Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I have an Azure HTTP Trigger that is being called by my HTML / Java Script. For some reason, I can call the HTTP Trigger via Java Script but the response is not thrown back. I keep getting the error: "There was a problem with the fetch operation:"

If I use Postman it works fine both sending and receiving the response. Is there something wrong with my Javascript or HTTP Trigger?

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic[] data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(requestBody);

        string area_harvested = data[0].Area_Harvested;
        string farmgateprice = data[0].FarmGatePricePHPPSA;

        log.LogInformation($"area_harvested: {area_harvested}");
        log.LogInformation($"farmgateprice: {farmgateprice}");

        // Create response message
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var content = new StringContent("Response content");
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        response.Content = content;

        return new HttpResponseMessageResult(response);
    }
}

public class HttpResponseMessageResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpResponseMessage _response;

    public HttpResponseMessageResult(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        _response = response;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.StatusCode = (int)_response.StatusCode;

        foreach (var header in _response.Headers)
        {
            response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
        }

        if (_response.Content != null)
        {
            foreach (var header in _response.Content.Headers)
            {
                response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
            }

            await _response.Content.CopyToAsync(response.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  body: testData,
  header: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
};

try {
  const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
  }

  const responseData = await response.text();
  console.log('Response data:', responseData);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
}
```

Comment: Can you check in the network if you're really sending the request to the right URL? Also what's the error message or status code?

Comment: Yes I am using Application Insights and the right URL is being called. How do i check the error message? I only get an Error in the HTML end when the console.error in catch(error) is called.

Also I know the HTTP trigger works fine since I am able to get responses back via Postman

Comment: In your developer tools, check in the network tab the response status code. You could be hitting the endpoint just fine and it shows in application insights but you could be sending a bad request or you're unauthorized.